# Login failure with workbench.developerforce.com and schemalister.herokuapp.com

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm able to login fine using my standard Exact Target login.

However, I'd like to start using tools such as workbench.developerforce.com and schemalister.herokuapp.com.

When I try logging in with them, I get a login failure. I've reviewed this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Login - and didn't see anything obvious.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two mentioned services aren't mentioned to work with **Marketing Cloud/Exact target**. They are dedicated to work with **Salesforce Core** organizations (i.e. SalesCloud, ServiceCloud) but Marketing Cloud/Exact target is a separate product which was obtained by Salesforce some time ago and still, they are not compatible platforms.

A metaphor can be used to explain this: It's like trying to use Chrome extension in Firefox.